# Bind a CIVector's component with NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, core-image

I'm trying to bind a CIVector's components with several NSSlider, each is binded with a different component of the CIVector.

More specifically, I'm trying to bind CITemperatureAndTint.inputTargetNeutral.X with an NSSlider using the following code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *bindingOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                 forKey:NSValidatesImmediatelyBindingOption];
 [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                 forKey:NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption];


 [temp_slider bind: @"value" 
       toObject: filter
    withKeyPath: @"inputTargetNeutral.X" 
        options: bindingOptions];
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X.

What's is the cleanest way to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CIVector` is immutable. You can't change its components after it has been created. The binding is trying to do so when the slider's value changes. What you apparently want to have happen is for the `inputTargetNeutral` property of the filter to be set to a new `CIVector` with the changed X component. That's not straightforward.

I was thinking you might implement a reversible `NSValueTransformer` to take a `CIVector` and give its X component. However, the reverse operation needs to get a Y component from somewhere and it doesn't have access to the original `CIVector`.

So, you may need a wrapper class for the filter. It would have a property `inputTargetNeutralX`. The getter would return the wrapped filter's `inputTargetNeutral.X`.  The setter would read its `inputTargetNeutral.Y`, combine that with the passed-in new X value to create a new `CIVector`, and set the filter's `inputTargetNeutral`. In order to have KVO-compliance, you'd implement `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingInputTargetNeutralX` to return an `NSSet` containing `@"filter.inputTargetNeutral"` (assuming the wrapper filter is held in a property named "filter").  See the docs for [`+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-SW4).

You'd do the same for the Y component.

You can actually do this with a category on `CIFilter` instead of a wrapper class. Of course, that would add those properties to every `CIFilter` in your app, not just `CITemperatureAndTint`s. You'd use `self` instead of "the wrapper filter" in my previous description, and simply leave "filter." out of the `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingInputTargetNeutralX` result to have it be implicitly `self`-based.

Edit: I forgot to point out the obvious: after you've created these new `inputTargetNeutralX` and `inputTargetNeutralY` properties, that's what you'd bind to.